# Dust.js tags for keys containing spaces

Tags: object, tags, escaping, dust.js

I wish to know how to write dust tags for keys containing spaces in [linkedIn's Dustjs](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/), or if it is even possible to do so.

According to this [Dust Tutorial](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-Show_me_some_Dust) the format of a dust tag should be `{xxxxxx}`, but I haven't found any information on what defines a valid `x`.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "street address": "North pole 1"
}
```

Failed attempts:

```
template = '{street address}';
template = '{street\\ address}';
template = '{"street address"}';
template = '{[street address]};
template = '{["street address"]};
```

Of course I know that I can just call it `streetAddress` and be done with it. But what I need to know is if I need to add certain restrictions on user-defined key names.

**Follow-up question**

If it is not possible to have space, what characters are allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed for keys in Dust. A Dust key<sup>[1](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/5bd1afc0dfcb43d7d271dd59d4e5d058344d1770/src/dust.pegjs#L131)</sup> must start with a letter from a - z (upper or lower case), an underscore, or a $, followed 0 or more characters in the set a - z (upper or lower case), 0 - 9, underscore, $, -.

It may be more clear as a regular expression:

`/[a-zA-Z_$]{1}[0-9a-zA-Z_$\-]*/`